# Why am I getting a "class not found" error in my Laravel module?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4

I am using "laravel/framework": "4.2. *" version, and I want to use the module system for my project. I have followed the instructions provided in [this document](http://creolab.hr/2013/05/modules-in-laravel-4/).

I can create modules by using the command: `php artisan modules:create module_name`. I have created an admin module in my app directory, and the module's directory structure has been created.

I am using `DB::select('some SQL statement')` in one of the actions of the controller from the admin module, but it is giving me the following error:

> Class 'App\Modules\Admin\Controllers\DB' not found.

Why is it not able to find this class?

Comment: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When using `DB` or any other Laravel facades outside the root namespace, you need to make sure you actually use the class in the root namespace. You can put a `\` before the class.

```
\DB::select(...)
```

Or you can use the `use` keyword in your class file to allow the use of a different namespaced class without explicitly writing out the namespace each time you use it.

```
<?php namespace App\Modules\Admin\Controllers;

use DB;
use BaseController;

class ModuleController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        // This will now use the correct facade
        $data = DB::select(...);
    }
}
```

Note that the `use` keyword always assumes it is loading a namespace from the root namespace. Therefore a fully qualified namespace is always required with `use`.

Answer (score 1):

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

Answer (score 0):

or else you can use autoload in composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
```

Comment: You can use phpstorm IDE editor which will help it will take care. It really helpful.Please try to use it.