# How to setup DB object for Testing using Codeception in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, namespaces, codeception

I want to use the DB object in a set of Codeception tests I am running inside Laravel.
Specifically, I want to do this as part of the _before of the test:

```
DB::table('name')->truncate();
```

At the beginning on my TestCest.php file I have this:

```
use \AcceptanceTester;
namespace App\Modules\Admin\Controllers;
use DB;
```

However, the DB object wont let me use it - I get a message

> Failed to login

when I run the codecept tests.

I am certain I am missing something basic about setting up the DB object, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: I've looked at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787376/laravel-modules-system-db-class-not-found - but still cannot make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it.

In tests/_bootstrap.php I placed the following code

```
// This is global bootstrap for autoloading
require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/autoload.php';
require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/start.php';
```