# Iron.io seems to be not detecting my database

Tags: php, api, laravel-4, iron.io

I tried to run my hello_worker.php but it doesn't seem to be detecting the database. I'm using Laravel 4.

This is my code in Iron.io:

```
<?php
// Worker code can be anything you want.
// echo "Hello!";
// print_r(getPayload());

// Simulating hard work for 5 seconds...
// sleep(5);

DB::table('test')->insert( array('content' => 'every one minute') );
// When you're ready press 'Run code ...'
```

This is the error that i received in my email.

> Message: Occurred during run: PHP Fatal error: Class ‘DB’ not found in /mnt/task/hello_worker.php on line 9

The API that im integrating http://www.iron.io/

Comment: With your current question we can't determine anything other than you have an error, please provide some code.

Comment: Have a look over this question and see if the answer fixes the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787376/laravel-modules-system-db-class-not-found

Comment: Also where are you running the code? that doesn't look like a controller or model

Comment: @Bankzilla in iron.io its not controller and model

Comment: @Bankzilla The API that im integrating http://www.iron.io/

Comment: If you're using them as helper files are they autoloaded? if not you'll have to use the namespace to find the database class. By the looks of the other answer its `use DB` and then reference everything with `\DB:table.....`

Answer (score 0):

I have been using iron.io just for the message queue. I ask iron.io to call specific URL in my Laravel app and process the request in the Laravel app not in the remote iron.io server.

Comment: yes i did that yesterday. using this `header("location: mywebsite.com");` but ddnt work

Answer (score 0):

To run code on IronWorker, you must include all your dependencies along with your worker. Whichever dependency has the DB class, you must include that. Here's an example worker with dependencies:

https://github.com/iron-io/dockerworker/blob/master/php/

You can use Laravel's database module / ORM (called [Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent)) outside of a Laravel app, here's some info on how to do that:

http://www.edzynda.com/use-laravels-eloquent-orm-outside-of-laravel/

Another option is to use Push Queues, which uses IronMQ to deliver messages to an endpoint on your application:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues#push-queues

Here's a video showing this in action:

https://vimeo.com/64703617

Hope that helps.