# Laravel concat in query

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to concatinate 2 tables for the blog using laravel, however i can't seem to get it working and i have no clue as to why..

if i use selectRaw i can see the concat but i lose all the blog content and i only see the author and nothing else.

I have tried to switch to raw and if i do the concat doesn't work but everything else works.

Here is the php code i am using:

```
 $app->get('/', function() use ($app) {

    $blog = $app->blog->selectRaw('CONCAT(users.first_name, " ", users.last_name) as author')->join('users', 'blog.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->get();

    $app->render('home.php', [
        'blog' => $blog
    ]);
})->name('home');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Eloquent [join](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins) function to achieve this.

For example

```
DB::table('blog')
            ->join('users', 'blog.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->select('blog.*', 'CONCAT(users.first_name, " ", users.last_name) as author')
            ->get();
```

Comment: well i did give it a try but that doesn't work, since class DB is not found

Comment: Try putting a `\\` in front of it. See details http://stackoverflow.com/a/25787734/170539

Comment: hold on let me edit the code section, thats how i currently have it since the other options don't work for this case